# Need help to troubleshoot the connection request made by a certain application with the external license server for license validation

Tags: windows-server-2019

This is my first time posting a question here. I resort to this forum after not getting much help from their technical support team. I'm trying to better understand what might cause the issue.

I've installed 2 server applications in the App server. These 2 applications require an HTTPS connection to their external license server to frequently check the license validity. The issue occurs when the application itself tries to connect to the external license server, it failed to reach. However, when I manually click on activate license button within the software, it successfully validates the license based on a similar network configuration. Any idea on what method could be perform to analyse the request/connection?

These Windows servers use 3 tier design: web server, app server, db server which runs in VM. The app server has access to the internet on port 443 for license activation through a proxy server to redirect the request to the outside world.

Answer (score 0):

This application might ignore your proxy settings for this regular license check function.

Depending on how you deploy your proxy settings in your organization there could be improvement to be done for this case.

Example which might help to troubleshoot: [Configure the proxy server manually using netsh command](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/security/defender-endpoint/configure-proxy-internet?view=o365-worldwide#configure-the-proxy-server-manually-using-netsh-command)

Often an application with such a function has an option to set a proxy especially for this purpose. Since you asked their support and couldn’t get a useful answer, I guess this application does not have this option.

Your last option would be to allow this server to browse the internet directly, bypassing the proxy. Depending on your firewall setup you’d be able to just allow this single connection and thus minimizing any risks.

Comment: Is there any difference in the aspect of the request path to the license server between user login to the server and then open the application to manually activate the license compare to the application itself automatically check the license? Because the first method working just fine, but the later results in failure. unable to contact the server.

Comment: Upon checking again in the App server, I found an error correspond to the attempt time for license activation in Event viewer. It stated the request to license server address cannot be resolved as the DNS didn't respond.

Comment: if there is a difference in the license check depends completely on the application itself.

Comment: hard to believe that this isse might be DNS related. Is this a popular application, can you share the name?
Otherwise i guess the supplier might be the only one who can help you.

Comment: the application is Novabackup Backup Server (xSP).